# r-410a pressure problem, 285/120 psig

Tags: hvac

i just installed a new split unit r-410a a/c system.   it is running at 285/120 psig.  the high side seems way low, should be about 420.  the correct orifice is installed.  this is a 1.5 ton condenser, 2 ton evaporator, and a 0.051 inch orifice.  thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Is this a mini-split ductless a/c unit? What is the make and model? Is it 120 V or 240 V?

Comment: Window units used to use chilled condensed water from the evaporator to help cool the condenser coils and presumably this would greatly reduce high side pressure. Do mini-split systems use this technique?

Comment: 230 volt, in the attic ducted evaporator.  not a mini system, 1 of 2 systems for the house

Comment: What was the outside temperature when you measured the pressures? What is the temperature of the air coming out of the condensing unit?

Comment: Is the evaporator unit putting out cool air?

Comment: How did you decide on the 0.051 inch orifice? Was this the specified one for the condenser? My Carrier system has been in service for 26 years and works acceptably. It is an R-22 , 12 SEER, scroll, 3.5 ton condenser unit and (IIRC) a 4 ton evaporator. It has a TXV. Given that this unit is a bit undersized for our application (only unit for a poorly insulated 2000 ft^2 tract house in hot Dallas TX, but surrounded by mature tall trees), I would bet that a fixed orifice would be just fine, but we haven't had any problem with it.

Comment: Did you have a long line set? Or longer than mfg's listing. If a long line set sometimes additional charge is needed. Was the system pumped down below 500 um , non compressables will affect the pressures.

Answer (score 0):

This may be normal for R-410a operating at an outside temperature of about 92 F [Edit: or maybe ambient of 75-80 F, so the air coming out of the condensing unit is 92 F].

See http://www.arkema.com/export/shared/.content/media/downloads/products-documentations/fluorochemicals/Forane-410A-Pressure-temperature-chart.pdf

**EDIT**

If you Google "operating pressures for R-410a" you will get 420 psi for the high side, *assuming* the air coming off the condenser is 120 F. What it the temp of the air coming off yours? Maybe your condensing unit has such an effective fan system that it cools the condenser better than the average fan.

There is of course the possibility that your system is not operating optimally and so not pumping enough heat to produce the proper condenser temperature. Is your evaporator unit/circulating fan producing the expected flow of chilled air?